# Why can't I parallel operation when I use either delay() or yield() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A, Code B and Code C get the same result *Result All*.

I think the Code B or Code C should get the result *Result MyThink* because I have added either *delay()* or *yield()*.

It seems that *flow.collect {...}* is a block function.

**Code A**

```
fun foo(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    println("Flow started")
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(500)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling foo...")
    val flow = foo()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value ->run {                     
                                println(value)  
                              } 
                 }
    println("Done")    
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun foo(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    println("Flow started")
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(500)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling foo...")
    val flow = foo()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value ->run {                     
                                println(value)  
                                delay(200)
                              } 
                 }
    println("Done")    
}
```

**Code C**

```
fun foo(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    println("Flow started")
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(500)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling foo...")
    val flow = foo()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value ->run {                     
                                println(value)  
                                yield()
                              } 
                 }
    println("Done")    
}
```

**Result All**

```
Calling foo...
Calling collect...
Flow started
1
2
3
Done
```

**Result MyThink**

```
Calling foo...
Calling collect...
Flow started
1
Done
2
3
```

Comment: The answer must be in the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#asynchronous-flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that flow.collect {...} is a block function.

That's not true in a literal sense, but there really is behaviour here that you might phrase as "blocking".

[`collect`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html) is a suspending function, which will return only after it has collected all of the items in the `Flow` that it was called on. Whenever the `Flow` suspends (with `delay` or `yield`, for example), the collection of the `Flow` is also suspended. This is all happening in the same coroutine (started by `runBlocking` in this case) that's suspended together. The `Flow` yielding values and `collect` processing them will continue after the suspension is over. Finally, when everything's collected, `collect` will return, and any code you have after it in that same coroutine will run.

This is consistent with the idea that coroutines are *sequential* by default, i.e. everything is executed top-to-bottom in your code, in order. If you want concurrent behaviour, you have to explicitly opt into it (for example, by launching new coroutines within the current one, with `launch`, or `async`). So what you call "blocking" is really just sequential. The `collect` function does *not* work like registering a listener would with many other APIs.

To understand the basic idea behind `Flow`, and how collecting it works within the same coroutine, I always recommend [this talk](https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=352670453).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have similar behavior as in Rx
you can use onEach instead collect with launchIn(this)

flow.onEach {
print(it)
}.launchIn(this)

https://proandroiddev.com/from-rxjava-2-to-kotlin-flow-threading-8618867e1955